# Prove absolute convergence from alternants

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, divergent-series

He failed to get the show in its entirety in this series, one I could indicate how working with this kind of series?
$$ \sum \limits^{\propto }_{n=1}\frac{(-1)}{n(\ln(n+1))^{2}} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\left|\frac{-1}{n\log^{2}\left(n+1\right)}\right|=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n\log^{2}\left(n+1\right)}=\frac{1}{\log^{2}\left(2\right)}+\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{1}{n\log^{2}\left(n+1\right)}\leq\frac{1}{\log^{2}\left(2\right)}+\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{1}{n\log^{2}\left(n\right)}\leq\frac{1}{\log^{2}\left(2\right)}+\frac{1}{2\log^{2}\left(2\right)}+\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t\log^{2}\left(t\right)}dt
 $$ by [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). And so $$\sum_{n\geq1}\left|\frac{-1}{n\log^{2}\left(n+1\right)}\right|\leq\frac{1}{\log^{2}\left(2\right)}+\frac{1}{2\log^{2}\left(2\right)}+\frac{1}{\log\left(2\right)}.
 $$ Note that if the series is $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n\log^{2}\left(n+1\right)}
 $$ you can conclude that it is convergent by [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Answer (score 1):

We may use [Cauchy condensation tes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)t.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over{n(\ln(n+1))^2}}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty{1\over{(n-1)(\ln(n))^2}}<\infty\\
\iff \sum_{n=2}^\infty{e^n\over{(e^n-1)(\ln(e^n))^2}}<\infty\\
\iff\sum_{n=1}^\infty{e^n\over{(e^n-1)n^2}}<\infty\\
\iff\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over{n^2}}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over{(e^n-1)n^2}}<\infty
$$
$${1\over (e^n-1)n^2}<{1\over n^2}$$
So by comparison test we see that the given series converges.